# Is there a better way to get an ISO Ttimestamp from mysql?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, iso8601

I want to get an ISO8601 timestamp from mysql but the best approach I can come up with is:

```
select
  REPLACE(
    CONCAT(
      DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s")
      , '+'
      , TIME_FORMAT(timediff( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,utc_timestamp ), "%H:%i")
    )
    ,'+-'
    ,'-') as dumptime
```

So I first generate the date and time representation.

Then I append a "+".

and lastely I calculate the offset to UTC and format it as hour and minute.

A negative offset will give me something like "-01:00", a positive will give me for example "01:00".

So the concatenation will leave me with something like "2019-12-13T04:05:06+-01:00" for a negative timezone offset. The `replace` will take care of it, removing the "+".

But: Is there a better way I didn't find in the docs?